# Is it true that Sub-Zero is the only character to appear in every Mortal Kombat game?

Tags: video-games, mortal-kombat

I was watching a video on YouTube, something like "top 10 Mortal Kombat characters ", where they list off their choice of rankings one by one while giving a short bio. Sub-Zero was # 2, there have been 2 people to use that title, and apparently he's the only person to be in every game.

I don't know how you can have Sub-Zero in a game without Scorpion in there with the urge to rip his spine out.

I don't know, if he is the only one to have a never ending appearance streak, tell me. If not, can you tell me who has?

Comment: according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mortal_Kombat_characters), yes.

Comment: So there are no others? At all?

Comment: not according to the chart on wikipedia. i've only played a few of the games, so i don't know if it's accurate.

Comment: That won't help. I have literally played EVERY mk title and still can't remember the answer to my question.

Answer (score 18):

No. Sub-Zero was notably absent in the prequel game "[Mortal Kombat: Special Forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat:_Special_Forces)", widely acknowledged to be the worst **MK** game ever (although not the [worst PSX game ever](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NHjJPAkPzYU))

[image]

As @phantom42's [chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Mortal_Kombat_characters#Character_overview) shows,  Sub-Zero has the largest number of appearances of any character, showing as a playable in pretty much all of the other mainstream games (along with all the films and TV shows). Liu Kang and Scorpion are also pretty prolific, appearing in all but MK5 and MK3 respectively.

Comment: so, he seems to have been in all of the *fighting* games, just not all of the games in the franchise (this seems to be a platformer).

Comment: This seems to be the only game that (chronologically) pre-dates his own origin-story game.

Comment: Maybe the worst MK *game*, but not [the worst thing](https://youtu.be/TGO8_Uva1GM?t=7m34s) to come out of the series...

Comment: @KSmarts - I've no idea what you're talking about. That looks **bloody brilliant**. Can I still get tickets?

Comment: There was also a Mortal Kombat game in which he was the [*only* playable character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_Mythologies:_Sub-Zero).

Answer (score 11):

Sub-Zero is the only person to be a **playable character** in every Mortal Kombat fighting game. However, other characters have *appeared* in every Mortal Kombat fighting game.

Liu Kang appears Mortal Kombat: Deadly Alliance, but is killed at the beginning of the game, and is not playable. He is a playable character in every other fighting game.

Sonya Blade also appears in every Mortal Kombat fighting game, but only has cameo roles in Mortal Kombat II and Mortal Kombat: Deception.

Raiden has a special cameo appearance in Mortal Kombat 3 and the updated rerelease Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3, but is not playable. He is a playable character in every other fighting game.

Scorpion was not in Mortal Kombat 3, but he was added to Ultimate Mortal Kombat 3, and appears in every other game.

---

You may have noticed that I keep saying "fighting game". That is because there have been games in the Mortal Kombat series that are more action/adventure platformers than fighting games. These include [Mortal Kombat Mythologies: Sub-Zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_Mythologies:_Sub-Zero) and [Mortal Kombat: Special Forces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat:_Deadly_Alliance), neither of which were well-received, and, despite being canon, are often not considered when one speaks of "Mortal Kombat games".

Comment: The FMV in Mortal Kombat Mythologies: Sub-Zero is [so-bad-it's-good](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MDA_-H6uXFw)

Answer (score -3):

I find it interesting that since Sub-Zero is 2 different people...One answer to this question (because we all know some will disagree with me) is that there is not a single fighter who has appeared in every main game. However...I myself just realized that if you count MK Tournament Edition as a true port of DA than Bi Han (as Sub in MK1 and Noob in every other title) does actually appear in EVERY game...but then X came out and ruined that. :(. So Bi-Han had the longest running title spanning from MK1-MK9

Answer (score -10):

Sub zero was in every MAJOR MK game released. He was two different people but the same nickname. However, one person was in every mk game released. That is bi-han. He was sub zero until he died. Then he came back as noob saibot. Now I win a conversation that is really old.

Comment: Neither Sub-Zero nor Noob Saibot seem to appear in "Mortal Kombat: Special Forces" mentioned in Valorum's answer above.

Comment: Notice how I said MAJOR. That does not include special forces, sub zero mytholigies, and shaolin monks.

Comment: Then your answer is off-topic, as the question wasn't limited to MAJOR games. Valorum's answer is still a more accurate answer, not to mention far more timely. ;)

Comment: Ok. When you say I like mortal kombat, that didn't mean those other low budget games. Mortal kombat is a fighting game that involves to people fighting on the screen. Mk 1,2,3,Ultimate 3,4,deadly alliance,deception,Armageddon,komplete edition, and X. Along with some other unknown games like tournament edition and advance. The three I listen before are not original style mk games. The ones I listed are why mk X is called mk X . It is the tenth.